# GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to list my contacts with '*GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts*' and always have **401 (Unauthorized)**.

My application on *apps.dev.microsoft.com* has permissions:

- **Contacts.ReadWrite** (both delegated and application permissions)

My client application has authentication scope: *https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite*

Other API like 'me' or 'users' works fine.

I tried to list my contacts using Microsoft Graph Explorer (*https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer*) with enabling relevant scopes and it never worked for me. Any hints on how to resolve it are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Copy your access token and parse it at https://jwt.io. Check the `scp` claim to see if it actually contains the scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

...

  "oid": ".....",
  "platf": "....",
  "puid": "....",
  "scp": "Contacts.ReadWrite Directory.ReadWrite.All People.Read.All User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ],

Comment: @JasonJohnston Just in case, I tried with just a single scope Contacts.ReadWrite scope and it didn't work...

  "scp": "Contacts.ReadWrite",

Comment: I missed that you said it doesn't work in Graph Explorer either. In that case do you get any text in the error response? Is it also a 401?

Comment: @JasonJohnston I am trying to invoke https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts in the Graph Explorer with my test account from my own active directory on azure. The scope "Contacts.ReadWrite" is enabled. I get "Failure - Status Code 401". Response: "code": "UnknownError" ...

Comment: @JasonJohnston at the same time, Graph Explorer is able to list all my users in my AD with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: Well /users and /me/contacts are completely different things. /users is against the AD, while /me/contacts is trying to access the personal contacts stored in the user's Exchange online mailbox. Do you have Exchange Online mailboxes?

Comment: I see. In fact I don't have user's Exchange online mailbox for my AD users. And as for my corporate account I am not sure if we have one. That is very unfortunate. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep. The Graph only works with cloud data, so that would explain it. I'll add it as the "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph can only access cloud data, so in order to access personal contacts, you need to have an Exchange Online mailbox in Office 365. ([reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/users-you-can-reach)) From your comment, you don't have an Exchange Online mailbox so unfortunately the `/me/contacts` endpoint won't work for your users.